# Firewall Exclusion or local use only for C#/.net IpcChannel

Tags: c#, .net, ipc, windows-firewall

We have created a program that uses IpcChannel for local inter process communication.

On all development and test systems, it did not rise a firewall alert.

On a customer system, it does not work unless it gets a firewall exclusion. Unfortunately, the path of the program changes, so it has to be excluded over and over again.

Also, I only need local access - which I thought I configured.

How to either use it differently so it does not need an exception or how to unblock it in the firewall? I am not aware on what ports I would have to open - or why. Again, program exclusion in the local Windows firewall sadly doesn't work due to changing path.

(Also, I am not 100%ly sure it is the IpcChannel, though I don't have anything else in the program, I am pasting the full code.)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider provider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
    provider.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;
    IDictionary properties = new Hashtable();

    var name = args.LastOrDefault();

    var portName = Funcs.GetUniqueIdentifier(); // string based on machine name and session
    var remoteObjectName = name ?? "MyApiRemoteObject";
    properties["portName"] = portName + remoteObjectName;
    properties["exclusiveAddressUse"] = false;
    IpcChannel serverChannel = new IpcChannel(properties, null, provider);

    var reader = new MyApiReader();
    RemotingServices.Marshal(reader, remoteObjectName);

    var endTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3);
    while (DateTime.Now < endTime && !MyApiReader.ShouldExit && !Console.KeyAvailable)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
    RemotingServices.Disconnect(reader);
}
```